# React-native packager doesn't detect code changes and I have to restart everytime

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm on Windows 8 and I'm new with React-native. 
If I change my code in Atom, the react packager doesn't detect any change.
The procedure is:
-react-native start
-react-native run-android
-Changes on code
-I try to Reload (R-R) on Genymotion but nothing change
-I kill react packager
-react-native start
-I reload on Genymotion and I can see all changes.

This is uncomfortable because when I reload on Genymotion I have to wait the process for a lot of minutes.

How can I resolve this?
There is a way to reload quickly my changes?

Comment: There are problems with watching the files in Windows. It usually takes a few more seconds. For Meteor, React-native and any file watchers, better to use Mac or Linux. React native development works well on Mac.

Comment: That assumes that if I want to develop on Windows , I spend my time to wait the packager ? There is no any solution ?

Comment: I had the same problem. There is a solution mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7257) ,it worked for me.